# Combining random forest variable importance p-values from multiply imputed datasets

Tags: r, p-value, random-forest, multiple-imputation, importance

I am using the ranger package in R to construct random forests on 10 imputed datasets after implementing MICE to fill in missing values. The ranger package provides not only a variable importance measure (VIMP) but also a p value for each VIMP following the method described in this paper: https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/25587/ Briefly, negative VIMP scores are used to construct an empirical null distribution that is symmetric around 0, and p values are calculated as the proportion of values in the null distribution that are higher than the VIMP.

My question is, how do I accurately pool the VIMP from the different imputations and get a pooled p value that reflects the uncertainty in the imputed values? To pool the VIMP I would just take the mean across imputations, but what about the p value? There are no standard errors in a random forest to work with like one would when pooling regression results. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

1/4/21 (Happy New Year!) I came up with a possible solution but I don't know if it is mathematically sound. Would appreciate any feedback. My idea was to calculate the variance of each empirical null distribution and take the variance of these variances to get a measure of the variance between imputations. I could then add this to the estimate of within imputation variance (the mean of variances for all imputations) to get an estimate of the pooled variance. Finally, I could artificially inflate the pooled VIMP estimates so that their distribution had the same variance as the calculated pooled variance estimate. Does this hold up?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06897.pdf (Choosing between methods of combining p-values, Heard and Rubin-Delanchy) may help, however, one problem will be that your p-values aren't based on independent samples, and, therefore, don't have a clearly-defined joint distribution under the null hypothesis.  If the samples *are* independent, and not just the imputed values, then you are in a much better position.